# Parsing specific paragraph VIA Tika or POI

Tags: java, parsing, apache-poi, apache-tika

Hello Everyone m new to java and i just wanted to ask that wheather we can parse through a docx file using apache poi or tika and extract a certain pargaph with specific headings if its possible please guide me

Comment: Should be easy with Apache POI - iterate through all the paragraphs, checking the styles or text contents as you go. What did you try, and how far did you get before you got stuck?

Comment: i am basically doing pattern matching and giving start of the paragraph but i dont know how to detect end of the paragraph

Comment: Either use Apache POI directly, and iterate over paragraphs, or call Tika in XHTML mode then split on the `<p>...</p>` tags